# How to add a column with images using flextabale()?

Tags: r, flextable

I am trying to add a column with images to the table :
In this example, I use the same image in each row, but my actual data has a different image.

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)

img.file <- file.path( R.home("doc"), "html", "logo.jpg" )
data = iris %>% mutate(path= img.file)
myft <- flextable( head(data))
```

I am following examples listed in [fleaxtable table](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/as_image.html) ,

```
myft <- compose( myft, j = "path",
                 value = as_paragraph(
                   as_image(src = path, width = .20, height = .15),
                   " blah blah ",
                   as_chunk(Sepal.Length, props = fp_text(color = "red"))
                 ),
                 part = "body")
```

when I run it, I get error :
[image]

I try to read the documentation, but I can't find any explanation of what to do to fix the error. In the code I provided, it actually adds an image and text "blah blah" to the cell, but all I want is to render a path as an image. I tried to shorten the code to the following:

```
myft <- compose( myft, j = "path",
                     value = as_paragraph(
                       as_image(src = path, width = .20, height = .15))
                     ),
                     part = "body")
```

But it did not work.
Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a wrong function! The `colformat_image()` do teh trick

```
myft <- colformat_image( myft, j = "path", width = .20, height = .15)
```

[image]